# How to segregate the values between ^ special characters in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I need to get the value no specific fixed length between special character in separate columns in oracle

Ex: provided two sample values

```
1^1^1^C^2^315^2000^YES

900^1^15^C^1^1070^50^NO
```

Output should be

```
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5   val6   val7   val8

1     1    1    C    2     315   2000  yes

900   1    15   C    1     1070   50   No
```

Regards
sathish

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use regular expressions:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1^1^1^C^2^315^2000^YES' from dual union all
  3     select '900^1^15^C^1^1070^50^NO' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) val1,
  6         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) val2,
  7         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) val3,
  8         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 4) val4,
  9         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 5) val5,
 10         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 6) val6,
 11         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 7) val7,
 12         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 8) val8
 13  from test;

VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  VAL4  VAL5  VAL6  VAL7  VAL8
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
1     1     1     C     2     315   2000  YES
900   1     15    C     1     1070  50    NO

SQL>
```

---

Another option, which might behave better (read: faster) on large data set is a combination of `substr + instr`:

```
  5  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '^', 1, 1) - 1) val1,
  6         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 1) + 1,
  7                     instr(col, '^', 1, 2) - instr(col, '^', 1, 1) - 1
  8               ) val2,
  9         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 2) + 1,
 10                     instr(col, '^', 1, 3) - instr(col, '^', 1, 2) - 1
 11               ) val3,
 12         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 3) + 1,
 13                     instr(col, '^', 1, 4) - instr(col, '^', 1, 3) - 1
 14               ) val4,
 15         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 4) + 1,
 16                     instr(col, '^', 1, 5) - instr(col, '^', 1, 4) - 1
 17               ) val5,
 18         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 5) + 1,
 19                     instr(col, '^', 1, 6) - instr(col, '^', 1, 5) - 1
 20               ) val6,
 21         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 6) + 1,
 22                     instr(col, '^', 1, 7) - instr(col, '^', 1, 6) - 1
 23               ) val7,
 24         substr(col, instr(col, '^', 1, 7) + 1) val8
 25  from test;

VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  VAL4  VAL5  VAL6  VAL7  VAL8
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
1     1     1     C     2     315   2000  YES
900   1     15    C     1     1070  50    NO

SQL>
```